# __init__ cannot import name from separate .py file

Tags: python

I am trying to pass two arrays from one python file (`agent.py`) to a new module (`moea.py`).  The MOEA file utilizes PyGMO, if anyone also has any expertise on that.

In short, I am building two arrays, A and B, which will control the mechanics of the MOEA search.

In agent.py, I have:

```
self.A = []
self.B = []
*code that fills A and B*
problem = R()
```

In moea.py, I have:

```
import agent

class R(base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(R,self).__init__(len(self.A),0,4)
        self.set_bound(0,len(self.B))
```

This is giving an error that moea.py cannot find object A or B.  The purpose of the `__init__` is to create a population of entries containing `len(self.A)` different variables ranging between 0 and `len(self.B)`.

EDIT:
The purpose of this edit is hopefully to clarify the question at hand.  I believe this question can be simplified down to "Is it possible to import data from other .py files into a separate `__init__` without changing the number of input variables."  I have changed some of the other code while testing some other ideas.

agent.py:

```
import moea

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, ...)
        self.A = []
        self.test = 2
        *other attribute statements*
    def function(...)
        self.A = [] #To clear the array on subsequent uses
        *code to fill A*
        problem = moea.R()
```

In moea.py I have:

```
import agent

class R(base) #using the _base definition from the link below
    def __init__(self):
        print agent.Agent.test
        super(R,self).__init__(len(agent.Agent.A),0,4)
        ...
```

My issue is that the test statement says that the Agent attribute test does not exist.  Why is it able to find the agent.py file, and the Agent class in that file, if it cannot also find the attributes attached to that class?  If I could get class R's `__init__` to read some of agent's attributes the code would be complete.

Information on the base class can be found here:  [PyGMO documentation](https://github.com/esa/pagmo/blob/master/PyGMO/problem/_base.py)

Comment: Have you imported agent module? from agent....?

Comment: `self` in that `__init__` refers to the `R` object you are creating.  That can't be the same as whatever `self` is in the other file.  What is `self` in agent.py?

Comment: Can you show us the `base` class definition?

Comment: @kingAm I have an "import agent" in moea.py.  I'll modify question.

Comment: @PabloDíazOgni the base class definition comes from the PyGMO code, here is a [link](https://github.com/esa/pagmo/blob/master/PyGMO/problem/_base.py).  I can post it here as well, but since this is my first question I'm not sure on the social norms.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm not 100% sure how to answer this since I'm working off of someone else's code and am still learning Python, but I'm following the mechanics used to pass information through the agent structure.  The agent is made up of many other files and calling functions from other files has been accomplished through `self.agent2.function(*inputs*)`.  I'm just copying those methods.

Answer (score 0):

In agent.py:

```
import moea

self.A = []
self.B = []
*code that fills A and B*
problem = moea.R(self.A, self.B)
```

In moea.py:

```
class R(base):
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        super(R,self).__init__(len(A),0,4)
        self.set_bound(0,len(B))
```

In short "It's better to be explicit than implicit" and in your situation there would be no other way to do it without circular imports which (IMO) creates even more of a mess. Also, I changed the import to the other file (I didn't see how R would be available without that import)

Comment: I tested this, but it seems there's a conflict with the _base.py code in PyGMO.  In particular: `__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`  `_base.py` is trying to call the `__get_deepcopy__`, which fails at the `return deepcopy(self)` command

Comment: I'd love to help you out, in fact I did (to the best of my abilities), but without further info I cannot track down the bugs....Looking at the PyGMO home page I was only barely comprehending the first paragraph....All of that being said, you have a number of beginner-level mistakes which leads me to the conclusion that you should spend about a week reading introductory python tutorials then dive into PyGMO. I'm sure you know enough to use the functionality of PyGMO, but you need to start somewhere, and for now that would be with a beginners python tutorial.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for the attempt at help then.  Although I'm confused how I have a number of mistakes in so few lines of code.  Is creating a blank array under the Agent class to use as a placeholder such a bad idea?  The build and use of the R class's __init__ definition is entirely out of my control.  Oh, and I pasted the link, for the PyGMO base code which laid out where the deepcopy was coming from in my earlier response.  If it helps at all it can be found here: [PyGMO source for _base](https://github.com/esa/pagmo/blob/master/PyGMO/problem/_base.py)

Comment: @DonGruber Where you album to solve this problem? I'm encountering the same problem. it looks like you cannot omit to give default value to init function __init__(self, dim=dim) but I don't want to hardcode it.